# HttpRequest cannot load... Invalid HTTP status code 404 but Curl works

Tags: angularjs, curl

I have a problem with my request.

Using Angular Chrome browser return:

```
OPTIONS http://example.it/api/v1/auth/sign_in 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.it/api/v1/auth/sign_in. Invalid HTTP status code 404
```

But trying with Curl

```
curl -XPOST -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://example.it/api/v1/auth/sign_in -d '{"email": "admin@example.it, "passoword": "administrator" }'
```

Everything is ok. Why?

I'm using NG Token Auth.

Comment: I suspect the backend is following REST semantics and doesn't have a route mapped to that URL for the OPTIONS verb. I'll bet that curl -XOPTIONS gives you a 404, as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS Origin inconsistency on HTTP OPTIONS request when testing with curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972551/cors-origin-inconsistency-on-http-options-request-when-testing-with-curl)